# Are there any time-based events?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

In Fallout New Vegas, do I have to keep an eye on the time/date? Are there any events that happen after a certain amount of ingame time?

Can you for example miss something if you arrive to late in a certain place or don't finish a quest until a specific day?

I remember that in Fallout 1 or 2 (or both?) you were on a deadline and things could happen in the world without your interaction.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the most part no. Some events will only resolve after a certain amount of time has been passed from a trigger, and you may occasionally need to let 3 days pass (or just wait in place 3 days) for a script reset or merchant restock, but there are no 'scheduled events' which require actual attention to the calendar.

A few quests can only be completed at night, or during the day, or at a certain time of day, but you can't 'miss' them, you'll merely need to wait for the time to roll around again.

Comment: +1 for a perfect answer, there's no way to improve upon this that I can see.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is one quest at [Camp McCarran](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/I_Put_a_Spell_on_You).

> You need to find and disable an explosive before time runs out.

Comment: From what I read it's mainly not time-depent though, but triggers depending on if or if not you first talk to the base's commander (or leave the base).

Comment: That's correct. The quest is *timed*, in that you have 5 minutes from the conversation, but not *time-sensitive* - you can delay it indefinitely.